# count of orders and shipping with users table on specific period

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

in laravel app i want to make report to count the orders and shippings request for each user in specific period
i am created two inputs to and from to choose the dates
then i want to make query to get the users and count for orders and shippings count in table
how can i make it ?
in user model i have two relationship like it

```php
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order' , 'user_id');
}


public function shippings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shipping::class);
}
```

in the order model

```php
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User' , 'user_id')
                ->withDefault(new User());
}
```

in the shipping model

```php
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User' , 'user_id')
                ->withDefault(new User());
}
```

i am trying to write many queries and this is the last one

```php
if (!empty($from) || !empty($to)) {
            $report = User::whereHas('shippings',function ($q) use ($from,$to) {
                    $q->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])->groupBy('created_at')->get();
                })->orWhereHas('orders',function ($q) use($from,$to){
                    $q->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])->groupBy('created_at')->get();
            })->orderByRaw('orders_count + shippings_count DESC')
                ->withCount(['orders','shippings'])->paginate(25);
            }else {
            $report = User::withCount(['orders','shippings'])->orderBy('shippings_count','desc')->paginate(25);
            }
```

can i any one help me ?

to get the orders and shippings for each user in specific period what i choose

Comment: What it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the same condition in `with()` and `withCount()` methods like in the `whereHas()` methods.
2. If you have `or` condition outside, I think it is better to split `whereBetween()` on two different statements `equal or more` and `equal and less`, because one of `$from` and `$to` could be empty.
3. If your `$from` and `$to` variables contain dates, it is easier and safer to use `whereDate()` method.
4. I think it is more clear to move your outside conditions inside callbacks, then you could use only one `User` call.

The final result should be like this:

```
$report = User
    ::withCount([
        'orders' => function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
            if (!empty($from)) {
                $q->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from);
            }
            if (!empty($to)) {
                $q->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
            }
        },
        'shippings' => function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
            if (!empty($from)) {
                $q->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from);
            }
            if (!empty($to)) {
                $q->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
            }
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('shippings',function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
        if (!empty($from)) {
            $q->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from);
        }
        if (!empty($to)) {
            $q->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
        }
    })
    ->orWhereHas('orders',function ($q) use($from, $to){
        if (!empty($from)) {
            $q->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from);
        }
        if (!empty($to)) {
            $q->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
        }
    })
    ->orderByRaw('orders_count + shippings_count DESC')
    ->paginate(25);
```

Or just add scope to your `Shipping` and `Order` models:

```
public function scopeWhereDateBetween($builder, $from, $to)
{
    if (!empty($from)) {
        $builder->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from);
    }
    if (!empty($to)) {
        $builder->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
    }
}
```

And then result should look like this:

```
$report = User
    ::withCount([
        'orders' => function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
            $q->whereDateBetween($from, $to);
        },
        'shippings' => function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
            $q->whereDateBetween($from, $to);
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('shippings',function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
        $q->whereDateBetween($from, $to);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('orders',function ($q) use($from, $to){
        $q->whereDateBetween($from, $to);
    })
    ->orderByRaw('orders_count + shippings_count DESC')
    ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: thanks very much it works fine , but i want to know if i need to add list of users and choose user and time period then get the result if not return all data 
can i make it or should be separated because when i try to make the two queries 
in the first query write first() but in the last query write get or pagination so how can i make forloop in the first one 
@IndianCoding

Comment: @Salmamehanny it is better to start another question with examples.